# I cannot open an excel spreadsheet due to the immense lag caused by the formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a few formulas that are very CPU intensive to run. When I open the spreadsheet, it just keeps loading forever. I cannot access any of the options or data. I have tried openning a blank spreadsheet and changing formula calculations to manual but the spreadsheet still does it anyway. How can I fix this issue?

Edit: I found a way to access the spreadsheet. I uploaded it to Google Drive and opened it with Google Sheets.

Comment: Formulas still calculate in Google sheets but VBA doesn't run and external references would not refresh. Have you tried opening the workbook in Excel's Safe Mode? If so, you would have the opportunity to correct the calculation lag.

Comment: The issue still ocurred in safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to upload the spreadsheet to Google Drive and open it with Google Sheets, which allowed it to be editted.